# How can I switch between "All" and "Unread" in my Outlook 2013 inbox?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2013

I would like to switch between seeing All and just Unread emails in my Outlook 2013 inbox using just the keyboard and a single key combo, for instance Ctrl+Shift+A and Ctrl+Shift+U (just an example).

Is there such a shortcut, or is it possible to create one?

The closest I have gotten is Ctrl+E to go to the search box, then Shift+Tab to jump to Unread and Shift-Tab again to get to All, then Space to select. Cumbersome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could map a few simple Macros in [AutoHotkey](http://www.ahkscript.org/) with something like this:

```
#SingleInstance
#Persistent
SetTitleMatchMode 2

Hotkey, IfWinActive, Outlook ahk_class rctrl_renwnd32, NUIDocumentWindow
Hotkey, +u, ViewUnreadLabel
Hotkey, +a, ViewReadLabel
Hotkey, IfWinActive

SafeToRunMacro() {
    IfWinActive, ahk_class rctrl_renwnd32
    {
        ControlGetFocus, CurrentCtrl
        CtrlList = Acrobat Preview Window1,AfxWndW5,AfxWndW6,EXCEL71,MsoCommandBar1,OlkPicturePreviewer1,paneClassDC1,RichEdit20WPT2,RichEdit20WPT4,RichEdit20WPT5,RICHEDIT50W1,SUPERGRID1,SUPERGRID2,AfxWndW16,OutlookGrid1,NetUIHWND4
        if CurrentCtrl in %CtrlList%
        {
            Return, True
        } else {
            Return, False
        }
    }
}

ViewUnreadFunc(NormalKey) {
    if SafeToRunMacro() {
        ControlClick, OutlookGrid1, ahk_class rctrl_renwnd32,,,, NA x60 y5
    } else {
        Send %NormalKey%
    }
}

ViewReadFunc(NormalKey) {
    if SafeToRunMacro() {
        ControlClick, OutlookGrid1, ahk_class rctrl_renwnd32,,,, NA x5 y5
    } else {
        Send %NormalKey%
    }
}

ViewUnreadLabel:
    ViewUnreadFunc(A_ThisHotkey)
Return

ViewReadLabel:
    ViewReadFunc(A_ThisHotkey)
Return
```

If you're interested you can compile this into a .exe file and start it each time you start your PC.  I'm working currently on implementing this into my Outlook GTD tool.  If you're interested you can learn more at [AutoGTD.com](http://www.autogtd.com/)

Comment: Should've been some builtin shortcut, but thanks for this tip, for some reason didn't occur to me!

Answer (score 2):

So I wound up using a combination of the above tips, thanks everyone!

- Created a custom view for only unread messages
- Created a macro to switch between ordinary compact view and only unread messages view
- Created a Quick Access Toolbar button for the macro, which can be
  used via Alt+the number corresponding to the buttons placement on the
  QAT.

This is the macro:

```
Sub SkifteView()

Dim ns As Outlook.NameSpace
Set ns = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")

Dim Exp As Outlook.Explorer
Set Exp = Application.ActiveExplorer

Dim myInbox As Folder
Set myInbox = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

Set Exp.CurrentFolder = myInbox

If Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentView.Name = "Compact" Then
   Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentView = "Only unread"
Else
    Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentView = "Compact"
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that comes to my mind is to open *two* Outlook main windows: one for **Inbox** and another for **Unread Mail** search folder (you can right-click it and select **Open in New Window**).

After that you'll be able to switch between windows using <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

I created a new view (copy of Compact) and set it to only show unread.
Then added the Change View command to the Quick Action Toolbar which I use a lot.
It still requires 2 clicks, but it's an easy solution and pretty quick.